# ¿Porqué no es necesario invocar al método toString en Java?

Tags: java

la duda que tengo es como bien dice la pregunta, porque no es necesario a la hora de mostrar la información de un objeto llamar o invocar al método `toString()` de la siguiente manera:

```
    // Porque solo con poner el objeto ya te dice la información del objeto 
    System.out.print(Objeto); 
    // y no es necesario ponerlo así.
    System.out.print(Objeto.toString());
```

Comment: Todo es por la forma como lo interpreta el compilador. El compilador invoca implicitamente el metodo `toString`.. esa vendria ser la razon..

Comment: @MrDave1999 Nitpick: No es el compilador, es la implementación del método PrintStream#print(Object)

Comment: @SJuan76 Si, tienes razon.. Efectivamente, el metodo [print](https://github.com/openjdk-mirror/jdk7u-jdk/blob/master/src/share/classes/java/io/PrintStream.java#L682) invoca al metodo [valueOf](https://github.com/openjdk-mirror/jdk7u-jdk/blob/master/src/share/classes/java/lang/String.java#L2901) y de ahi viene la magia.. Gracias por el dato

Answer (score 2):

En java todos los objetos heredan de la clase `Object` la cual contiene el método `toString()`.

Por esa razón en el  código:

```
System.out.println(objeto);
```

No es necesario llamar explícitamente  el método `toString()` ya que la función sabe que todos los objetos tienen ese método por heredar de `Object`.

Pero para que funcione correctamente una clase debe sobreescribir el método `toString()` para que muestre información personalizada. En el siguiente ejemplo la clase A no sobreescribe el método `toString()` así que se usa el método heredado de la clase Object. La clase B sí lo sobreescribe para mostrar un texto relacionado a la clase B. En ambos casos no es necesario llamar implícitamente el método `toString()`:

```
public class Test {


    static class A{
        int a;
    }

    static class B{
        int b;

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "objeto b contiene un valor: " + b;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String... args){
       A a = new A();
       B b = new B();

        System.out.println(a);
        System.out.println(b);
    }

}
```

**Actualización:**

El siguiente código muestra una sobrecarga del método `println` la cual recibe como parámetro un objeto. Internamente llama a la función `String.valueOf()` para obtener el valor `string` de ese objeto:

```
public void println(Object x) {
        String s = String.valueOf(x);
        synchronized (this) {
            print(s);
            newLine();
        }
    }
```

Esta es una sobrecarga de la función `valueOf` que recibe un objeto, se puede ver como llama el método `toString()` del objeto que se le pasa:

```
public static String valueOf(Object obj) {
        return (obj == null) ? "null" : obj.toString();
    }
```

Comment: Si, todo eso lo entiendo, que el método toString es de la clase padre Object y que si quieres personalizar la información debes sobreescribirlo, pero sigo sin saber  porque no es necesario invocarlo y como solo con poner el objeto sabe por si solo que método escoger y de esos coger el toString().

Comment: Es decir, porque de todos los métodos que tiene el objeto ya sean heredados o no por defecto sin invocar ningún método invoca a toString() y no por ejemplo a hashCode().

Comment: Es por la implementación, internamente se llamará el método `toString()` del objeto. Puedes verlo con más detalle en la actualización de la respuesta.

Answer (score 1):

Lo que sucede es que tienes 2 (en realidad tiene muchas más) versiones sobrecargadas de `print`:

```
public void print(String cadena) {
    // implementación para escribir una cadena
}

public void print(Object object) {
    this.print(object.toString());
}
```

O algo por el estilo. Un ejemplo: https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/7817963ce91384380fe65005a6c438b08b022bad/src/java.base/share/classes/java/io/PrintStream.java#L876